# If file data starts with a certain hex sequence, run strings command on the file

Tags: files, string, recursive

I want to recursively crawl a directory and if the file has `\x58\x46\x53\x00` as the first 4 bytes, I want to run `strings` on the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
h_signature=$(echo 58465300 | tr 'a-f' 'A-F')
read -r x a b x <<<$(od --endian=big -N 4 -t x2 yourfile | tr 'a-f' 'A-F')
case "$a$b" in "$h_signature" ) strings yourfile ;; esac
```

Meth-2:

```
dd if=yourfile count=4 bs=1 2>/dev/null |
perl -lpe '$_ = uc unpack "H*"' | xargs test "$h_signature" = && strings yourfile
```

Meth-3:

```
head -c 4 yourfile | xxd -ps -g 4 | grep -qwi "$h_signature" && strings yourfile
```

Comment: Hi a little tangental question: added this to my makefile `xfs:
 @find assets/ -type f -not -name ".txt" -print0 | \
 xargs -0 -P 1 -n1 -I {} \
 head -c 4 {} | xxd -ps -g 4 | grep -qwi $(echo 58465300 | tr 'a-f' 'A-F') && strings {} -n 5` however it is giving me issues with grep, is it possible to modify your answer so it searches a directory recursively?

Comment: @sp334 I am sorry I missed seeing your comments & queries. Here's one possible solution to your requirements. Hope you still find it useful.  `find assets/ -type f -not -name "*.txt" -exec perl -0777ne 'exit !/^\x58\x47\x53\x00/' {} \; -exec strings {} \;`

Answer (score 2):

If you this is a file type you use regulary, I would define it in your `~/.magic` (or even in the system magic file):

```
0 long 0x00534658 XFS-file
```

(assuming you are on a little endian system). Now you can test with the `file` command:

```
$ file testfile
testfile: XFS-file
```

And you can do this for testing:

```
if [[ `file -b testfile` == XFS-file ]]; then strings testfile; fi
```

Answer (score 1):

To see if a file's first four bytes is the specific string `XFS\0` (which the hexadecimal byte sequence in the question corresponds to):

```
if od -N 4 -a file | grep -qF 'X   F   S nul'; then
    strings file
fi
```

`od -N 4 -a` will convert the first four bytes of the file to its one-byte character display format.  We use `grep -qF` to test the output of `od` against what we're looking for.

On a little-endian machine, you may use `od -N 4` without any additional flags and instead grep for `043130 000123`.

Alternatively:

```
if od -N 4 -A n -c file | tr -d ' ' | grep -qF 'XFS\0'; then
    strings file
fi
```

Comment: But the spec is to look for is a `hex` string rather than an ascii string. `od` needs `-x` instead of `-c`.

Comment: @RakeshSharma Well, the hex string (or rather, the byte string given by the sequence of hexadecimals) is equivalent to the ASCII string `XFS\0`.

Comment: So the step to map the hex seq --> ascii string should be mentioned for completeness sake. And what if the hex seq has \x30 then the tr -d step will make it error prone.